# Método para calcular pontuação

Tags: java

Tenho um ficheiro `resultados.txt` onde está o id das duas equipas e quantos golos cada uma marcou no jogo.

Através desse ficheiro cria-se um outro ficheiro onde fica o nome da equipa, os pontos totais dessa equipa, quantas vitórias teve, quantos empates, quantas derrotas, quantos golos sofreu e quantos golos marcou, ordenado desde a equipa que tem mais pontos até a que tem menos.

E queria fazer uma função que fizesse-me isso dando o ficheiro dos resultados como input.

Regras:

- A equipa que ganha soma 3 pontos.
- Em caso de empate, cada equipa soma 1 ponto.
- Derrota soma 0.

Código:

```java
public int[] CalculoClassificacao(int[]array) {
    int i = 0;
    int[] arrayClass = new int[7];
    while(i<array.length) {
        array[i] = i * 2;
        i++;
    }

    try {
        String nomeFicheiroResultados = "classificacao-final.txt";
        String newLine = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        File ficheiro = new File(nomeFicheiroResultados);
        FileWriter escritor = new FileWriter(ficheiro);
        for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
            String texto = array[j]+ newLine;
            arrayClass = array;
            escritor.write(texto);
        }
        escritor.close();
    } catch(IOException err) {
        System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro: " + err);
    }

    return arrayClass;
}
```

Ficheiro CSV:

```
1;5;2;1   
2;4;0;4
```

Comment: Em qual lingugem? Qual é o formato dos dados que estão no ficheiro? Podes editar  a pergunta acresentando um exemplo sff

Comment: Cadê a linguagem? Cadê o formato dos dados?

Comment: Em java, os dados estão no formato csv.

Comment: Por favor não adicione imagens para representar códigos e nem trechos de seu arquivo, isso dificulta quem for te ajudar a testar o problema.

Comment: O que me aconselha a fazer?

Comment: Sugiro você amazenar os dados em um formato estruturado como xml ou json, facilitando a leitura tanto para pessoas como para programas.

Comment: Leia isso: [**Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: @diegofm agora consegue ajudar?

Comment: E como está seu csv? Pode adicionar algumas linhas dele na pergunta também?

Comment: @diegofm já adicionei linhas do meu ficheiro csv

Comment: Não está faltando dados nesse CSV não Ider? Você disse que cada arquivo CSV possui "Nome da equipa, os pontos totais dessa equipa, quantas vitórias teve, quantos empates, quantas derrotas, quantos golos sofreu e quantos golos marcou". O seu exemplo de CSV tem 4 colunas.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly esse CSV   "Nome da equipa, os pontos totais dessa equipa, quantas vitórias teve, quantos empates, quantas derrotas, quantos golos sofreu e quantos golos marcou", será criado através de outro csv que tem por base os resultados que tem esse formato de apenas 4 colunas! E quero criar um método que dando esse ficheiro resultados.txt consiga fazer esse cálculo para preencher o csv da classificação

Comment: Ok, o que é esse CSV de quatro colunas? Id da primeira equipe, id da segunda equipe, quantidade de gols da primeira equipe e quantidade de gols da segunda? E de onde você vai tirar o nome da equipe para criar o segundo CSV? Talvez valha a pena atualizar a pergunta com todas as entradas necesárias (explicando o que é cada coluna) e um exemplo da saída esperada.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly sim é isso mesmo. Através do id da equipa consegue-se chegar ao nome

Comment: Sua pergunta parece estar boa agora. Dei o meu voto de reabertura (já tem 2). Quando a sua pergunta acumular 5 votos de reabertura, ela é reaberta.